# Assign method call to button click in parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, event-handling

I created a custom message window, like a MessageBox, but with a button disabled until checkbox is checked.

I want to:

1. Pass a method from any other class as a parameter to the constructor of this message window.
2. Bind this method to a button click so that when it's clicked the method is executed.

I'm new to C# and am a bit confused. I suspect it has something to do with delegate, Func, EventHandler etc, and I even sorted out how delegates and events work, but this is a bit too much for me.

The question is if it's possible and if yes, what is the logic behind this? Any examples, maybe?

I really doubt I'm the only one who ever needed it.

Comment: Create a view model class with an ICommand property. Bind the Button's Command property to the view model property. Search the web for MVVM and commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that passes a EventHandler using a constructor:

[Two approach was described (Lambda, Method)]

```
class TestWindow
{
    public TestWindow(RoutedEventHandler ButtonClickHandler)
    {
        SomeButton.Click += ButtonClickHandler;
    }
}

class Caller
{
    void Test()
    {
        TestWindow A = new TestWindow((S, E) => {
            // Event Handler Codes ...
        });

        TestWindow B = new TestWindow(ClickHandler);
    }

    private void ClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Event Handler Codes ...
    }
}
```